# Probability of cube to get all 6 numbers

Tags: probability

I have a supposed simple question about a stochastic exercise.

We throw a fair cube $n \ge 6$ times. What is the probability to get all 6 different numbers in our result? For every $n \ge 13 $ the probability should be greater as $ \frac{1}{2} $.

I thought the number of different results is $ {6+n-1 \choose n} $ because we sample without sequence and with replacement. From this results I only have to grab those, which have all 6 numbers in it. So this should be $ {6 \choose 6} \cdot {6+n-6-1 \choose n-6} = {n-1 \choose n-6}$. Here I take $6$ from $6$ without sequence and without replacement to ensure that all numbers are in the sample and then I take the rest with replacement and without sequence.

The problem is that for $ n \ge 13 $ the probability $ \frac{n-1 \choose n-6}{6+n-1 \choose n} $ is not greather then $ \frac{1}{2}$. Some of my thought must be wrong but I can't figure out where my mistake is. Can you please explain to me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Hint: What is the probablitity we do not get 4 as a result in one roll? What is the probability we do not get 4 as a result in any of $n$ rolls? What is the probability we do not get 6 as a result in any of $n$ rolls?....

Comment: We do not get a 4 as a result in n rolls with a probability of (5/6)^n right? Of course this is equal to all other numbers. So we get a 4 with the probability of 1-(5/6)^n but what is the advantage of this view?

Comment: Hint: Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Just try in this way:
`P(get 6 different) = 1 - (P(get 5) + P(get 4) ... + P(get 1))
P(get 1) = 6 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * ... * 1
P(get 2) = 6 * 5 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * ... * 2
P(get 3) = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * ... * 3
P(get 4) = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * ... * 4
P(get 5) = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 5 * 5 * 5 * ... * 5
P(get 6) = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 6 * 6 * ... * 6`

Comment: @GrahamKemp Okay thanks that might work (have to try it but with 6 sets it is so much to calculate). Can you please explain to me why my method does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we count how many strings with $n$ characters over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ have an occurence of every element of the alphabet: this is exactly the number of surjective functions from a set with $n$ elements into a set with $6$ elements, hence by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the answer is given by
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{6}(-1)^{6-j}\binom{6}{j}j^n = 6!\cdot{n\brace 6} $$
i.e. by a multiple of a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). On the other hand, the total number of strings is clearly given by $6^n$, hence it is enough to check that
$$ \frac{6!}{6^{13}}{13\brace 6}>\frac{1}{2}$$
to prove our claim, and the LHS of the last inequality is $\approx 51,4\%$ by direct computation.